# how to draw spline graph in excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have checked spline graph in excel-2013 chart. But MS-Excel does not provide spline chart support. Does anyone know a workaround solution to render spline chart without using add-on and algorithm to generate points?

Answer (score 3):

Excel's XY Scatter chart with the "smoothed line" option ticked uses a spline, to be precise, of the many different types of splines, it uses a Bezier spline.

[image]

More details about the interpolation used by Excel see [here](https://blog.splitwise.com/2012/01/31/mystery-solved-the-secret-of-excel-curved-line-interpolation/)